# Pandas - Take current row, compare value to X previous rows and return how many matches (within x% range)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas column like so:

```
index colA
1     10.2
2     10.8
3     11.6
4     10.7
5     9.5
6     6.2
7     12.9
8     10.6
9     6.4
10    20.5
```

I want to search the current row value and find matches from previous rows that are close. For example index4 (10.7) would return a match of 1 because it is close to index2 (10.8). Similarly index8 (10.6) would return a match of 2 because it is close to both index2 and 4.

Using a threshold of +/- 5% for this example would output the below:

```
index colA  matches
1     10.2    0
2     10.8    0
3     11.6    0
4     10.7    2
5     9.5     0
6     6.2     0
7     12.9    0
8     10.6    3
9     6.4     1
10    20.5    0
```

With a large dataframe I would like to limit this to the previous X (300?) number of rows to search over rather than an entire dataframe.

Comment: Um, 10.2 is within a +/- 5% threshold of 10., so a couple of your matches are off by 1.

Comment: Yep, originally had it as an aboslute value. Premise is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using triangle indices to ensure we only look backwards.  Then use `np.bincount` to accumulate the matches.

```
a = df.colA.values

i, j = np.tril_indices(len(a), -1)
mask = np.abs(a[i] - a[j]) / a[i] <= .05
df.assign(matches=np.bincount(i[mask], minlength=len(a)))

       colA  matches
index               
1      10.2        0
2      10.8        0
3      11.6        0
4      10.7        2
5       9.5        0
6       6.2        0
7      12.9        0
8      10.6        3
9       6.4        1
10     20.5        0
```

---

If you are having resource issues, consider using good 'ol fashion loops.  However, if you have access to `numba` you make this considerably faster.

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def counter(a):
    c = np.arange(len(a)) * 0
    for i, x in enumerate(a):
        for j, y in enumerate(a):
            if j < i:
                if abs(x - y) / x <= .05:
                    c[i] += 1
    return c

df.assign(matches=counter(a))

       colA  matches
index               
1      10.2        0
2      10.8        0
3      11.6        0
4      10.7        2
5       9.5        0
6       6.2        0
7      12.9        0
8      10.6        3
9       6.4        1
10     20.5        0
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please elaborate on `i, j = np.tril_indices(len(a), -1)`? I'm getting a memory error on only 110k rows so looking for a way to replicate it if possible. Cheers.

Comment: This is an order n^2 problem.  110k is definitely going to blow you up.  Let me put something that won't break your memory, but will still likely take a while.

Comment: @swifty I've updated my answer.  The looping should avoid any n^2 memory issues.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a numpy solution that leverages broadcasted comparison:

```
i = df.colA.values
j = np.arange(len(df))

df['matches'] = (
    (np.abs(i - i[:, None]) < i * .05) & (j < j[:, None])
).sum(1)
```

```
df

   index  colA  matches
0      1  10.2        0
1      2  10.8        0
2      3  11.6        0
3      4  10.7        2
4      5   9.5        0
5      6   6.2        0
6      7  12.9        0
7      8  10.6        3
8      9   6.4        1
9     10  20.5        0
```

Note; This is extremely fast, but does not handle the 300 row limitation for large dataframes.

Answer (score 3):

`rolling` with `apply` , if speed matter , please look into cold's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49217330/7964527)

```
df.colA.rolling(window=len(df),min_periods=1).apply(lambda x : sum(abs((x-x[-1])/x[-1])<0.05)-1)
Out[113]: 
index
1     0.0
2     0.0
3     0.0
4     2.0
5     0.0
6     0.0
7     0.0
8     3.0
9     1.0
10    0.0
Name: colA, dtype: float64
```